# posgres returns empty rows if json_agg doesn' find nothing

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Hello guys i'm facing a problem when using json_agg

i have two tables : docs and subs that look like this

```
Docs(
id primary key,
title,
name,
code
)
Subs(
id primary key,
title,
name,
code,
idoc fk
)
```

and i use this query to retrieve them

```
SELECT *,s.subdocs FROM docs d INNER JOIN(
    SELECT idoc,json_agg(
        json_build_object(
        'id',id,'title',title,'name',name,'code',code,
    )) AS subdocs FROM subs GROUP BY subs.idoc
    ) AS s ON s.idoc = d.idoc
 WHERE d.id = 4
```

It seem to work when there is a sub doc associated with the doc but when there is not the query doesn't return anything so how can i check if the result of the json agg is empty and to return at least the fields of the docs table?

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like you need to use left join :

```
SELECT *,s.subdocs FROM docs d 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT idoc,json_agg(json_build_object('id',id,'title',title,'name',name,'code',code)) AS subdocs 
    FROM subs GROUP BY subs.idoc
    ) AS s ON s.idoc = d.idoc
 WHERE d.id = 4
```